# how can I fix an error in MeasurementBlockProvider in VS2010 when viewing a WPF app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf

In VS2010 I'm building a small WPF app. It's pretty simple, a few StackPanels, a few Grids and a ListView. I'm using VS2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. When I view the XAML designer, I get an error in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.MeasurementBlockProvider`, here's the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.MeasurementBlockProvider.EventWrite_BeginLevel(UInt32 componentId, UInt64 ticks, UInt64 cpuTicks, UInt64 size, Guid correlationId, UInt32 sequenceNumber, UInt32 nestingLevel, Guid parentCorrelationId, UInt32 parentSequenceNumber, String category)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.MeasurementBlock.Begin()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.MeasurementBlock.Begin(UInt64 size, String category)
   at MS.Internal.PerformanceRegistrar.MeasurementBlockTracker.StartTiming(UInt64 codeMarker, String description)
   at MS.Internal.Performance.StartTiming(PerformanceMark mark)
   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem..ctor(EditingContext editingContext, DesignerContext designerContext, Func`2 getMetadataCallback)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
```

There's also another exception in the window that says `Not enough storage is available to complete this operation`. Not sure what that's about, I've got 300 or 400MB free.

Anyone know a workaround for this? The google was no help.